# How to Filter a Pandas DataFrame Based on Value Counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with company name, year, and total environmental cost. I would like to reduce the data frame to only companies who I have five years of data points for. I have used .valuecounts() to see which companies fit this criteria but I can't figure out how to use this to filter the my overall dataframe.

```
print(reduced_df)
Company_Name  Year Total_Environmental_Cost
39                           3M CO  2019             -2.059334e+09
44     HONEYWELL INTERNATIONAL INC  2019             -6.350976e+08
47             GENERAL ELECTRIC CO  2019             -8.590171e+08
56              SOUTHWEST AIRLINES  2019             -6.854033e+09
57            ALASKA AIR GROUP INC  2019             -2.640410e+09
...                            ...   ...                       ...
13998        COSTCO WHOLESALE CORP  2010             -4.688026e+08
14001                 TIFFANY & CO  2010             -1.298038e+07
14007                     EBAY INC  2010              1.731209e+07
14022     UNITED NATURAL FOODS INC  2010             -3.812594e+07
14024                MCKESSON CORP  2010             -4.513375e+07

company_count = reduced_df["Company_Name"].value_counts().loc[lambda x: x > 4]
print(company_count)

3M CO                        10
BAXTER INTERNATIONAL INC     10
PITNEY BOWES INC             10
MARRIOTT INTL INC            10
CABOT CORP                   10
                             ..
KEURIG DR PEPPER INC          5
DIGITAL REALTY TRUST INC      5
UNIVAR SOLUTIONS INC          5
MGM RESORTS INTERNATIONAL     5
FIFTH THIRD BANCORP           5
Name: Company_Name, Length: 236, dtype: int64
```

I've tried using .filter and .index with no success.

Comment: try this:
`filtered_df = reduced_df[reduced_df["Company_Name"].isin(company_count.index)]
`

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I was putting .index in the wrong place.

Comment: Adding it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `groupby`:

```
output = reduced_df[reduced_df.groupby("Company_Name")["Year"].transform("count").gt(4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

(answer from comments)

try this:

```
filtered_df = reduced_df[reduced_df["Company_Name"].isin(company_count.index)]
```